# Nextjs build uses different modules for html and js files

Tags: javascript, next.js, server-side-rendering, hydration

I have a JavaScript component library (`mylib`) that support both **cjs** (commonjs) and **mjs** (esm). If we check the `node_modules/mylib` there will be 2 folders `cjs/` and `mjs/`. And the `package.json` has conditional export to use between **cjs** and **mjs** according to the project settings.

[image: mylib folder structure]

```
"exports": {
   "import": "./lib/mjs/index.js",  // projects with module = esm
   "require": "./lib/cjs/index.js", // projects with module = cjs
 },
```

`mylib` has a component `Button`. In order to debug i have updated the `mylib/cjs/Button.js` and `mylib/mjs/Button.js` file so that cjs/Button render "CJS" always and mjs/Button render "MJS" always

Now I am trying to use `mylib/Button` inside a nextjs project. So ive installed mylib as a dependancy. When i build the project, the nextjs build the html file with the `mylib/cjs/Button` and build the JavaScript files with `mylib/mjs/Button`. This is causing hydration issue.
See the `console.log` from the terminal and browser console.

[image]